# Running a simple hello world from the console after installing IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, console-application

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA on my mac and wrote the simplest Kotlin program

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){

    println("Hello")
}
```

I can run it from the IDE environment. (It prints Hello of course)

My question: **How can you run this from the console?**

What I have done:

I tried to call

```
java simplekt.class
```

but I got 
`Error: could not find or load main class simplekt.class`

I tried `java simplekt` but then I got an `exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

I tried to use `kotlin` or `kotlinc` but the command was not found. (where is the compiler installed?)

In [this resource](https://www.codexpedia.com/kotlin/install-compile-and-run-kotlin-from-command-line/) they use kotlinc and they produce a jar file but IDEA only output a class file.

Not really sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @IEE1394: One case is that you're working on a commandline tool that takes commandline arguments and you want to test it with different args as you go.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application from the IDE, in the `Run` window the very first line is the command that the IDE executes to start your program. In my case it's something like:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 <a lot more omitted>
```

You can execute the same command in your terminal and that will execute the application. Reading that line will also (indirectly) tell you where the `kotlinc` command is installed, and in my case – using MacOS – it's at `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlinc`

However, you can always decide to entirely stop using the IDE and compile/run your program from the command line by following instructions here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html

Comment: It might be worth adding that the line may be very long and you might have to click on the `...` to get the full version. Then also it might include some spaces in filenames that need to be either escaped or quoted.

Comment: i did the exact same thing: copied & manually pretty-printed the whole command, doing find--> there's no mention of `kotlinc` anywhere. the structure is like the following when using gradle:

```"...\java.exe" "-javaagent:...\lib\idea_rt.jar=55555:...\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath "\build\classes\kotlin\main;
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10.jar;kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10.jar;
kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar;kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar;annotations-13.0.jar" MainKt```

these same components were in diff order & from diff dirs for `-classpath` when building on intellij.
what should i do?

Comment: kotlinc is the compiler and doesn't get invoked when running the code (unless you're running Kotlin scripts). What happens is that kotlinc generates class files (exactly like javac) that get executed on the JVM

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by @user2340612 is mostly right, but maybe due to software changing or some differences in what i did, it did not work for me. Following did:

- to avoid repetition, i'll be using the short name: `$(ideac) = "IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2"` in place of the full name

- the path to the `kotlinc` is this one: `$(ideac)\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin` 
  much similar to the one told above, but slightly different
- i have verified it to work in the command given in the [command-line](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html#create-and-run-an-application) doc linked above or [compiler-reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#compiler-options) too: `kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar`
- running the resultant .jar file via `java -jar ./hello.jar` shows the expected output
- there's no `kotlin-native` in that folder, so, couldn't verify this [native-command-line-compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-command-line-compiler.html#compile-the-code-from-the-console) kotlin doc

### Backstory/What did not work

- the command under the run tab in $(ideac) no longer shows the kotlinc path
- I had created the Kotlin "project" by using "new project" (intelliJ) or by "Kotlin multiplatform > JVM" (gradle)
- The run command for either of these did not contain any `kotlinc` in them
- I tried creating a new > "scratch" file; and it showed this: `$(ideac)\plugins\Kotlin\bin\windows\LLDBFrontend.exe` but i tried using that on CLI and it did not work either