# After building a Kotlin program in IntelliJ, how do I execute it directly from the terminal?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, command-line, terminal

I'm new to Kotlin and have no useful experience in Java.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Community Edition) on an M1 Mac.
My code builds and runs within IntelliJ but it's a commandline tool that takes arguments so I want to test it directly from the commandline passing it different files as arguments. (I'm aware I can edit the configuration each time to pass different commandline arguments.)

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355690/how-to-run-compiled-class-file-in-kotlin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733566/how-to-run-kotlin-class-from-the-command-line) but their answers are about running a `.jar` file whereas it seems to me that building the code in IntelliJ emits a `.class` file and not a `.jar` file. Though there is a `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, the existing answers make no mention of wrappers.

I'm assuming the build step emits something that can be run without another step. Is that assumption wrong? Do I have to manually create a `.jar` file from the `.class` file on the command-line in order to run it because IntelliJ doesn't emit the final "executable"?

I seem to be missing some step or prior knowledge that existing answers don't address, perhaps they assume familiarity with Java?

Comment: After posting I found another previous question that received little attention but does have the answer: [Running a simple hello world from the console after installing IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508023/running-a-simple-hello-world-from-the-console-after-installing-intellij-idea)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382636/2000323 about the way to do this with Gradle.